# Control KeyDown Event Trap CTRL-C etc

Tags: vb.net, forms, controls

I'm having a problem with processing CTRL-C, CTRL-V, CTRL-X on my form.

```
Private Function HandleKeyDown(sender As Object,
                                   e As KeyEventArgs,
                                   ByVal vShow As String) As Boolean
        HandleKeyDown = False
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.F1 Then
            Help.ShowPopup(Me, vShow, Cursor.Position)
        End If
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.C AndAlso e.Modifiers = Keys.Control Then
            sender.Copy()
        ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.V AndAlso e.Modifiers = Keys.Control Then
            sender.Paste()
        ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.X AndAlso e.Modifiers = Keys.Control Then
            sender.Cut()
        Else
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Modifiers:{0} KeyCode:{1} KeyData:{2} KeyValue:{3} ", e.Modifiers.ToString, e.KeyCode.ToString, e.KeyData.ToString, e.KeyValue.ToString))
        End If
        HandleKeyDown = True
    End Function
```

The KeyDown event never picks up the second key. The only value the KeyCode ever seems to hold is Keys.Control. This is what the Console.WriteLine outputs for CTRL-C

```
Modifiers:Control KeyCode:ControlKey KeyData:ControlKey, Control KeyValue:17
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Are you calling this from the actual event handler? I had to add "Handles MyBase.KeyDown" and remove your extra parameter.

```
Private Sub HandleKeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    'HandleKeyDown = False

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.C AndAlso e.Modifiers = Keys.Control Then
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Modifiers:{0} --- KeyCode:{1}  --- KeyData:{2}  --- KeyValue:{3} ",
                                      e.Modifiers.ToString, e.KeyCode.ToString, e.KeyData.ToString, e.KeyValue.ToString))
        'sender.Copy()
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.V AndAlso e.Modifiers = Keys.Control Then
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Modifiers:{0}  --- KeyCode:{1}  --- KeyData:{2}  --- KeyValue:{3} ",
                                      e.Modifiers.ToString, e.KeyCode.ToString, e.KeyData.ToString, e.KeyValue.ToString))
        'sender.Paste()
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.X AndAlso e.Modifiers = Keys.Control Then
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Modifiers:{0}  --- KeyCode:{1}  --- KeyData:{2}  --- KeyValue:{3} ",
                                      e.Modifiers.ToString, e.KeyCode.ToString, e.KeyData.ToString, e.KeyValue.ToString))
        'sender.Cut()
    End If

    'HandleKeyDown = True
End Sub
```

It's working for me. I get a value of 88, 67, and 86 respectively.

Comment: The function was called directly from the handlers, but I put the code directly into the Event Handler and it still doesn't work, all the values are for Control.  I'll forget it for now, I don't know why it's not working.

Comment: The only two things I'd recommend is trying a simplified test with just my code and rebuilding from there OR debug line by line and see if your boolean value is preventing your code from continuing. It could be something as simple as that. Other than that, the code I posted, works, I'm just not using your boolean.

Comment: Update your question with your Event Handler function as well.